# rewriterule for Apache to do reverseproxy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, proxy

I am running my Apache server with public DNS say `www.siteA.com`. I am hosting one internal site which is `www.siteB.com`.

I want to rewrite rule in .htaccess of my server so that if anytime a request comes to `www.siteA.com/getData/mydata.php` it proxies this request to `www.siteB.com/getData/mydata.php`

I have written this rule in siteA .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(getData.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.siteB.com/$1 [P]
```

But I get server internal error. What could be possible reason for this. How can I achieve this proxy?

i have enabled proxy_module and proxy_http_module. Do i need to write anything else to get proxy working?

Thanks
k2G

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways you can do this, either with a RewriteRule as you've attempted:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(getData\/.*) http://www.siteB.com/$1 [P]
```

Or you can use `ProxyPass`:

```
ProxyPass /getData http://www.siteB.com/getData
```

Note that this would work for anything following `getData`, e.g. it would match `getData/mydata.php` or `getData/some/other/path/file.php`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to find out proxy address from my main adress. So that means, if my request is coming like - http://myadress.domain.com. I want this to proxy to http://myadress.domain2.com. Is it possible?>

Comment: Not sure I understand. The above configuration would do that if you had it in the site config for `myaddress.domain.com`. I don't know if you are referring to [ProxyPreserveHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) to pass the host-header?